# Customer accordion, without the use of jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a really long form that I'm trying to create a clickable and tabbable(FocusOut of last input) accordion style effect which opens the next div while hiding the previous. Below is the html:

```
<form class="common">
    <div class="hidesfeildset"> 
    <feildset>
        <legend>Section Title:</legend>
            <label><input type="text"/></label>
                <label><input type="text"/></label>
     </fieldset>
     </div>
    <div class="hidesfeildset">
    <feildset>
        <legend>Section Title:</legend>
            <label><input type="text"/></label>
                <label><input type="text"/></label>
     </fieldset>
     </div>
    <div class="hidesfeildset">
    <feildset>
        <legend>Section Title:</legend>
            <label><input type="text"/></label>
                <label><input type="text"/></label>
     </fieldset>
</form>
```

And the js:

```
<script>
  $(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){

      $(".hidesfieldset").hide();
      $("legend").bind("click","focusout",function () {


          $(this).next(".hidesfieldset").toggle();

          });
      });

  </script>
```

I cant get this to work for the life of me, does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

THanks in advance,
Mark

Comment: you mean like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3VTNV/1/

Comment: almost perfect, but needs to have a on click event too

Comment: click on which element

Comment: Would suggest you fix up the spelling `fieldset` vs `feildset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misspelled "*fieldset*" (not feildset) on every **hidesfieldset** class name as well as the opening **fieldset** tags. Furthermore, you haven't closed your final **hidesfieldset** div.

I won't ask your reasons of you choosing the html structure you did, but here is a working fiddle for you to look at and learn from.

http://jsfiddle.net/s4vcX/

```
// hide all labels (inputs) except for those in the first fieldset
$("fieldset label").hide();
$("fieldset:first label").show();

// show when legend is clicked while hiding rest
$("legend").bind("click", function () {
  $("fieldset label").not($(this).nextAll("label")).hide();
  $(this).nextAll("label").show();
});


//handle shift-tab on first input of each field set
$("fieldset").find("input:first").bind("keydown", function (e) {
  if( e.shiftKey && e.which == 9 ) {
    $(this).closest(".hidesfieldset").find("label").hide();
    var previous = $(this).closest(".hidesfieldset").prev(".hidesfieldset");
    if(previous.length==0)
        previous = $(this).closest("form").find(".hidesfieldset:last");
    previous.find("label").show();
    previous.find("input").last().focus();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});

//handle tab on last input of each field set
$("fieldset").find("input:last").bind("keydown", function (e) {
  if( !e.shiftKey && e.which == 9 ) {
    $(this).closest(".hidesfieldset").find("label").hide();
    var next = $(this).closest(".hidesfieldset").next(".hidesfieldset");
    if(next.length==0)
        next = $(this).closest("form").find(".hidesfieldset:first");
    next.find("label").show();
    next.find("input").first().focus();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out. I`m new to jquery so this has been a huge pain in the ass.. as far as my spelling is concerned, not sure what was going on there, it was the end of a really long day.... yikes. THanks again.